# Can't reference two classes inside one?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I'm utilizing object oriented programming for the first time in Java and haven't had any issues until now.

I have a Customer class (irrelevant details omitted):

```
public class Customer {

  public String bikesOwned;

  public Customer() //Default Constructor
  {
    bikesOwned = "";
  }

  public Customer(String aBike) //Parameterized Constructor
  {
    addBike(aBike);  
  }


  public void addBike (String aBike) //Mutator Method for Bikes Owned
  {
      bikesOwned = aBike;
  }


  public String toString()
  {
    String returnBikes = bikesOwned.toString();
    return returnBikes;
  }
}
```

And I have a Bike Tester class which uses information from my Bicycle class:

```
public class bikeTester {
  public static void main (String [] args)
  { 
        Bicycle hisBike = new Bicycle(Bicycle.BikeType.Hybrid Bicycle.UserType.Men, 
            Bicycle.FrameMaterial.Carbon, Bicycle.BrakeType.Caliper, 
            Bicycle.Condition.Used, 29, 18, 10, "REI", "Black");

 Customer don = new Customer();
        don.setFirstName("Don");
        don.setLastName("Norman");
        don.setPhoneNumber("804 123-4567");
        don.setEmailAddress("dnorman@aol.com");
        don.addBike(hisBike);
        System.out.println(don);
        System.out.println();
}
```

My issue is that when I compile, I get this error:
"addBike(java.lang.String) in Customer cannot be applied to (Bicycle)".

I can't figure out why everything else is working except for `addBike`. Any ideas? Any input is very appreciated.

Comment: `addBike(java.lang.String)`. `Bicycle` is not a `String`.

Comment: Unrelated, but `bikesOwned` should be a `List<Bike>` if you want to own more than one, which is implied by "bike**s** Owned"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addBike` method receives a `String` parameter but you are sending a `Bicycle` type to the function. It's basically a type mismatch.

Try sending a `String`value to the function.

Or, change the parameter in the `addBike` method to `Bicycle` type.

Answer (score 3):

Your `addBike` method expects a `String` parameter:

```
public void addBike (String aBike)
```

But you're sending it a `Bicycle` parameter:

```
don.addBike(hisBike);
```

Either send the method a `String` or change the method to accept a `Bicycle` (or add another method of the same name which accepts a `Bicycle`).

It's not entirely clear to me *how* you would convert between a `String` and a `Bicycle`, especially given that the method itself is just setting a value called `bikesOwned` which itself is a `String` for some reason.  Maybe `bikesOwned` should be a list or collection of some kind and you want to *add* items to that collection?

The logic of what you ultimately want this code to do is up to you.  But the error itself is pretty straightforward.  `String` and `Bicycle` are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass a "Bicycle" instance from

```
don.addBike(hisBike);
```

into a method:

```
public void addBike (String aBike)
```

that takes a string parameter.

Either change your method to accept a Bicycle instance (and presumably add it to some array of owned bikes) or if you meant to just pass in the name of the bike for instance, change the call accordingly.